# Is it possible to log directly into chroot?

Tags: linux, debian, users, login, chroot

Lets say I boot up my computer and I see the login screen. When I log in as *myuser*, I want to be restricted to a certain root directory via. `chroot`.

Let's assume that the directory is `/chroots/myuser/`. Is this possible to do ? If so, how would it be accomplished ?

**Note:**
Just to be clear, I want to change the root directory, not the home directory.
The new root directory for the user will contain another OS like Debian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the user's default shell in /etc/passwd to the command (or a wrapper script for that command) that logs that user into the chroot.

Comment: I think maybe you will then want a separate `/etc/password` inside the chroot which lists bash, see eg. here: http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/howtos_ssh_only.html

Comment: @goldilocks I use `schroot` which has a `-s` flag, with which you can set the shell for the user that you log in as. It also updates the user in `/etc/passwd` to use that shell (in the chroot environment).